# Django put data from external api to Database

Tags: python, django

iam working on a django-project. And my goal is to receive data from the docker deamon and pass the information to a simple integrated Django-Database like sqlite3. I made it already to put the information output to the template. But how i can pass the data to this database. I tried it for month and i didnt get it.i hope some of you can help me. Some Code:

**docker_api.py** where the information comes in:

```
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError
from requests_unixsocket import Session
from requests import RequestException
from config.settings import DOCKER_API


def docker_requester(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        method, endpoint, data = func(*args, **kwargs)
        session = Session()
        call = getattr(session, method)
        resp = call(DOCKER_API + endpoint, json=data, timeout=30)

        if resp.status_code == 204:
            return True
        if resp.status_code == 201 or resp.status_code == 200:
            try:
                return resp.json()
            except JSONDecodeError:
                return True
        return False

    return wrapper


@docker_requester
def list_image():
    return "get", "images/json", None
```

This already works

**images.py**(acting like a view):

```
from dockerInspector.forms import ImageForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from dockerInspector.docker_api import list_image, pull_image, delete_image


def list_images_view(request):
    resp = list_image()

    images = []
    for res in resp:
        try:
            img_id = res["Id"].split(":")
            repo_tags = (
                res["RepoTags"] if res["RepoTags"] is not None else ["no_name:untagged"]
            )
        except KeyError:
            return render(
                request, "dockerInspector/list_image.html", {"images": images}
            )

        for r in repo_tags:
            name, tag = r.split(":")
            image = {"repo": name, "tag": tag, "id": img_id[1][:12], "full_name": r}
            images.append(image)

    return render(request, "dockerInspector/list_image.html", {"images": images})
```

**list_image.html**
This handles the incoming informations and send it to the template like this:

```
{% extends "dockerInspector/base.html" %}
{% block content%}
<table class="table table-light">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <div class="section-image_pulling">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" id="image_txt" class="form-control" placeholder="Image von Docker-Hub beziehen..."
                    aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2" />
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary pull" type="button" id="pull_bt">
                        Pull
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Image-Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Image-Tag</th>
            <th scope="col">Image-ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Image löschen</th>
            <th scope="col">Container starten</th>
            <th scope="col">Submit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        {% for image in images %}

        <tr>
            <td><a class="detail-link" href="#">{{image.repo}}</a></td>
            <td>{{image.tag}}</td>
            <td>{{image.id}}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" value={{image.full_name}} class="btn btn-danger delete">Image löschen</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Container starten</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the data is displaying. So far so good. For my project i need to save this ouput
to a database. Do anyone has an idea, how i can do it? Im working so long on this project
and i didnt get it.